# "Convex" polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let me define "convex" polynomials, as the smallest class $\mathcal{C}$ of functions $p:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined (inductively) as:

UPDATED (case 0 was missing):

0) $p(x)=x$, i.e., the identity, is in $\mathcal{C}$.

1) $p(x)= 1$ is in $\mathcal{C}$

2) $p(x)= 1- q(x)$, for $q\in \mathcal{C}$, is in $\mathcal{C}$.

3) $p(x) = c \cdot q(x) + (1-c) r(x)$, for some $c\in [0,1]$ and $q,r\in\mathcal{C}$, is in $\mathcal{C}$.

4) $p(x) = q(x) \cdot r(x)$, with $q,r\in\mathcal{C}$, is in $\mathcal{C}$.

So basically $\mathcal{C}$ include all constant $c\in[0,1]$ functions, and is closed under the operations of convex combination, $1-$, and multiplication.

Clearly for every $p\in \mathcal{C}$ and $x\in [0,1]$, $p(x)\in [0,1]$ too.

**Question:** Is this class of functions known? Can anything interesting be said about this class? For example I think that every continuous function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ can be approximated by functions in $\mathcal{C}$. Would this be some (trivial?) consequence of the Stone–Weierstrass theorem?

Thanks!

Comment: (info) Often, "smallest" is written as "for every $\mathcal{C}'$ satisfies the condition, $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{C}'$".

Comment: I'm not happy with your choice of terminology.  You have a convex set of functions, not a set of convex functions.

Comment: Wait, without $p(x) = x \in \mathcal{C}$, $\mathcal{C}$ becomes uninteresting.

Comment: Thanks, let me fix this JiminP

Comment: Is there a easy proof that $\mathcal{C}$ includes all constant functions? I am not seeing it right now.

Comment: p(x)=c, is obtained as   c*1+ (1-c)*0, where 1 and 0 are the constant 1 and 0 functions.

Comment: @RaMa2013 But, how to show that $p(x)=2 \in \mathcal{C}$?

Comment: @tetori, no just constants with $c\in [0,1]$, as specified.

Comment: Let $p\in\mathbb R[x]$ be a polynomial such that $p(x)\in [0,1]$ for each $x\in [0;1]$. Is $p$ in $\mathcal C$?

Comment: Alex, I guess that's the heart of the problem: I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

*(Too long for a comment)*

**Lemma 1.** If $f\in\mathcal C$ is not constant then $f^{-1}(\{0,1\})\subseteq \{0,1\}$.

*Proof.* The claim clearly holds for the functions from rules 0 and 1.
If in rule 2 it holds for $q$, then also for $p$ because $0$ and $1$ are simply swapped. If in rule 3 it holds for $q$ and $r$, it also holds for $p$ because a convex combination within $[0,1]$ can yield a boundary value only if at least one input is this boundary value. If in rule 4 it holds for $q$ and $r$, it also holds for $p$ because a product i s$0$ iff one factor is $0$ and the product is $1$ if both factos are $1$. 
Hence the claim follows by induction. $_\square$

As a corollary, *Alex Ravsky*'s tentative conjecture is busted: $\mathcal C$ does not contain all polynomials that map $[0,1]\to[0,1]$. For example, $p(x)=4x^2-4x$ is missing.

*(I thought I had more, but had to scratch it again)*

Comment: Wait, $f(x)=\frac12x$ is in $\mathcal C$ but $f^{-1}(\{0,1\})) = \{0,2\} \not\subseteq \{0,1\}$. Also, $p(x)=4x^2-4x$ maps $[0,1]$ to $[-1,0]$ not $[0,1]$. Am I missing something?

Comment: I guess you are only considering the restriction of $f$ to $[0,1]$, and you mean $p(x)=4x-4x^2$.